# NoClassDefError while doing Google places in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-places-api

I am trying to do a tutorial from androidhive on google places.The nearby places are shown in a listview but when i click on the button which takes me to the app,the app force closes with noclassdeferror.

MainAcitivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Google Places
    GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

    // Places List
    PlacesList nearPlaces;

    // GPS Location
    GPSTracker gps;

    // Button
    Button btnShowOnMap;

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Places Listview
    ListView lv;

    // ListItems data
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


    // KEY Strings
    public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place
    public static String KEY_NAME = "name"; // name of the place
    public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity"; // Place area name

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (!isInternetPresent) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // creating GPS Class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(this);

        // check if GPS location can get
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
        } else {
            // Can't get user's current location
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "GPS Status",
                    "Couldn't get location information. Please enable GPS",
                    false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Getting listview
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // button show on map
        btnShowOnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);

        // calling background Async task to load Google Places
        // After getting places from Google all the data is shown in listview
        new LoadPlaces().execute();

        /** Button click event for shown on map */
        btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        PlacesMapActivity.class);
                // Sending user current geo location
                i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
                i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

                // passing near places to map activity
                i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
                // staring activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        /**
         * ListItem click event
         * On selecting a listitem SinglePlaceActivity is launched
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String reference = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reference)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SinglePlaceActivity.class);

                // Sending place refrence id to single place activity
                // place refrence id used to get "Place full details"
                in.putExtra(KEY_REFERENCE, reference);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load Google places
     * */
    class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // creating Places class object
            googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

            try {
                // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
                // If you want all types places make it as null
                // Check list of types supported by google
                // 
                String types = "cafe|restaurant"; // Listing places only cafes, restaurants

                // Radius in meters - increase this value if you don't find any places
                double radius = 1000; // 1000 meters 

                // get nearest places
                nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                        gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * and show the data in UI
         * Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI from background
         * thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                     * */
                    // Get json response status
                    String status = nearPlaces.status;

                    // Check for all possible status
                    if(status.equals("OK")){
                        // Successfully got places details
                        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                            // loop through each place
                            for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                                // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                                map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                                // Place name
                                map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                                // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                                placesListItems.add(map);
                            }
                            // list adapter
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, placesListItems,
                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                    new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                                            R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                            // Adding data into listview
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                        // Zero results found
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                                "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                                false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

LOGCAT:

```
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.PlacesMapActivity
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:110)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-03 12:27:10.101: E/AndroidRuntime(10539):    ... 12 more
```

the line number 110 where the noclassdeferror is shown is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        PlacesMapActivity.class);
```

The manifest is :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- SinglePlaceActivity -->
        <activity android:name=".SinglePlaceActivity" android:label="Place Details">
        </activity>

        <!-- PlacesMapActivity -->
        <activity android:name=".PlacesMapActivity" android:label="Near Places Map View">
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Access Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Please help!!

Comment: what type of content your used in placemap activityclass

Comment: What do u mean by type of content?The placesmapactivity extends mapactivity.

Comment: k.have your import the google api[android 4.4.2] library in app.

Comment: Do u mean in the java build path of properties?Yes it has been set as the project build target.

Comment: have you use this xml file class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" at your map fragment in xml

Comment: show your xml file,for verify

Comment: No i havent done that.The xml file which supports PlacesMapActivity has MapView.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="05M-7qOGbEja9lx-KvTJ9QgTTxcsJJfFuyT1cIw"
/>

Comment: I have posted the xml.Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

My experience i have use this ususal method, i got the answer,try this,hope you help this.

map xml:

```
<fragment
       android:id="@+id/src_map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

activity class:

```
public class MapPlace extends FragmentActivity
{
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchresult);

     FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.src_map);
    SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragment;
    map = supportmapfragment.getMap();
    }
}
```

in manifest file:  use normal premission like network,wifistate,networkstate,finelocation and coarse location. and additionally add this modules in manifest file.

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="use your API key" />
```

Comment: Let inform me, you will get the answer